# bootstrap modal get to initial UI state after close

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using a Bootstrap 3 modal. I have a text input inside the modal and a link when clicked will create new text input fields below the first one to a maximum of 4 fields. My code works fine and it creates more input fields.

But, when I close the modal and open it again there are more than one input text field depending on the number of times I clicked the link previously. I don't want this to happen - when I close the modal and open it again I would like to see only one input text field (initial state) and not see the changes to the DOM in the modal. Is this possible?

[Link to my code](http://www.bootply.com/bwkCMj7uIR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the **hide.bs.modal** event based on the BOotstrap Javascript documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

First I would add a class to all the input elements and newly rendered div elements clearAfterClose for inputs and hideAfterClose for divelements. Then I would create my Jquery function as:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $('.clearAfterClose').val('');
  $('.hideAfterClose').hide();
})
```

This will fire whenever the modal is hidden and clear all input elements with the the clas **clearAfterClose** and hide all divs with the clas **hideAfterClose**. 
I created a codepen for demonstration [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGjqbj)

Comment: Isn't this easier than approved answer?

Answer (score 0):

It will always be there since you're editing the HTML. The modal won't go back to it's original state until you refresh the page, or set it back yourself. Just empty the container, and add the first input again when you close the modal. Pay attention to what's happening on the "$('div#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal'" event block.

Your JS (I refactored your original code a bit)

```
$('#additional-fields').on('click', function () {

  var emailInputList = $('div.email-input-list'),
    itemCount = emailInputList.children().length,
    newItem = $('<div class="form-group"><label for="txtFriendEmail' + itemCount + '" class="sr-only">Email</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="txtFriendEmail' + itemCount + '"></div>');

  if (itemCount < 4) {
    emailInputList.append(newItem);
  }

});

$('div#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {  
  $('div.email-input-list').empty().append($('<div class="form-group"><label for="txtFriendEmail0">Email</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="txtFriendEmail0"></div>'));      
});
```

Your HTML

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group clearfix" id="input-array">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 email-input-list">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtFriendEmail0">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="txtFriendEmail0">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <p class="form-group-input-helper"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="additional-fields">Add another friend's email</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

('#name of input field ').val('');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).